# knockout complex calculation

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have say 3 functions and one Main in my viewmodel function

```
var viewModel = function () {

 var self = this;
 self.MAIN= ko.observableArray(); //i will push stage1 function after filling data

function stage2()
{
var self = this;
self.subtype = ko.observableArray(); //in this i push one,two,three function data 
}

 function stage1()
{
 var self = this;
 self.TypeData = ko.observableArray(); //it holds subtype data of stage2 
 self.TotalAmount =  ko.observable("");
}

function one() 
{
 var self = this;
 self.id=ko.observable("");
 self.AmountPerInstallment = ko.observable("");
}
function two()
{
 var self = this;
 self.id=ko.observable("");
 self.AmountPerInstallment = ko.observable("");
}
function three()
{
 var self = this;
 self.id=ko.observable("");
 self.AmountPerInstallment = ko.observable("");
}

}


 ko.applyBindings(new viewModel()); //its in my document.ready
```

Well the functions may be bit confusing let me explain my view part and data flow

**MAIN** observable array is my source of data i push eveything into it .

*Layer 1* : MAIN (I loop through it i will have **TypeData**,**TotalAmount** under it )

*Layer 2* : TypeData(I loop through it i will have **subtype** under it )

*Layer 3* : under **subtype** i have my functions one,two,three with **AmountPerInstallment**

So what i need is i have to sumup AmountPerInstallment under subtype(Layer 3) and should fill it in `TotalAmount` which is in my `MAIN` observableArray .

Most important thing is when i change `AmountPerInstallment` the total amount should change dynamically

**My main view structure :**

```
<table id="partialservicetypes" data-bind="foreach:$root.MAIN">
    <tr>
        <td>
                @Html.Partial("_PaymentsHeader"); // this has total amount 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td>
             <table>

                 <tr >
                     <td data-bind="foreach:$data.TypeData"> 
       @Html.Partial("xyz") //inside this partial view i run subtype foreach
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Why are you posting this as a challenge? What exactly is your question?

Comment: my bad mate :) just wanna express my depth of complexity .

Comment: Well, this still looks more like a request than an actual question.

Comment: Now changed . any help is most welcome

Comment: I'm sorry, but adding a question mark to the title doesn't magically turn your post into a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your data structure,

If your  `TypeData` in your stage1 holds the same value of the `subtype` array of stage2.

```
function stage1()
{
 var self = this;
 self.TypeData = ko.observableArray(); //it holds subtype data of stage2 
 self.TotalAmount = ko.computed(function() {
    var amount = 0;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.TypeData(), function(stage2) {
      amount += parseFloat(stage2.AmountPerInstallment());
    });

    return amount;
  });
}
```

If your `TypeData` in your stage1 holds **an array of stage2 objects**.

```
function stage1()
{
 var self = this;
 self.TypeData = ko.observableArray(); //it holds subtype data of stage2 
 self.TotalAmount = ko.computed(function() {
    var amount = 0;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.TypeData(), function(stage2) {
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(stage2.subtype(), function(obj) {
        amount += parseFloat(obj.AmountPerInstallment());
      });
    });

    return amount;
  });
}
```

**Update** looks like your `AmountPerInstallment` is a string instead of number.

Comment: AmountPerInstallment  is `decimal ?` in my server model entities .

Comment: `huocp` fanstastic one . i hope 2nd one works for sure .! let me check it

Comment: `huocp` well may be minor fix needed i guess . `TypeData` holds `subtype` this will hold `AmountPerInstallment` . Thing here is if i have a 3 listItems under `MAIN` i.e [0],[1],[2] etc . [0] have totalamount likely every list have one . if i change `AmountPerInstallment` under listitem [1] how to change the TotalAmount value with `amount` .

Comment: Tried `self.MAIN()[0].TotalAmount = amount;` inside `stage1()` but it says `MAIN` is undefined rightly so . any fix is appreciated

Comment: @supercool confused me. Your `TotalAmount` is sum of all `AmountPerInstallment`, it's kind of read only, why you want to directly change `TotalAmount`?

Comment: yes you right it read only . but i if change `AmountPerInstallment` under listitem [1] the `totalamount` is not getting updated to i.e there may be `n` ListItmes and for each listitem there will be `totalamount` right ? . why i am trying to directly update totalamount is find no way . i hope it is clear what i am looking for .

Comment: The senario works well if i have only one listitem i guess . any workaround

Comment: it should auto updates if all your AmountPerInstallment are ko.observable. You may need to provide a working jsfiddle for people to help.

Comment: well added my main view can you please look into it . my all amountperinstallments are observables .

Comment: it's not about the view, it depends on how your compose your data structure.

Comment: gotcha :) ty for the supoort . cache issue .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a setter function, maybe you could do

```
Object.defineProperties(yourObject, {
  AmountPerInstallment: {
    set: function () {
      /** code that you want to compile when you change AmountPerInstallment */
    }
  }
});
```